# Azure PowerShell or CLI command to Provide a User with Owner access to a specific Web Application

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli, azure-security, azure-rbac

I have around 100 Azure Web Apps and Azure Functions which I created using Azure PowerShell and CLI, now I need to assign Owner Access to these Web Apps to users (Separate users for each Web Apps)

I am unable to find any sample for this, most sample are pointing to Assigning Resource Group Level Access, but not to the Specific Resource.

The task is achievable in the Azure Portal, just need the PowerShell or CLI command to assign users owner or contributor rights to these specific resources.

If possible please provide a sample command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Power Shell, you could use [`New-AzureRmRoleAssignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.resources/new-azurermroleassignment?view=azurermps-4.4.1) to do this.

For example.

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -SignInName "test@hotmail.com" -RoleDefinitionName Owner -Scope "/subscriptions/*************/resourceGroups/shuiapp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/shuicli"
```

or

```
New-AzureRmRoleAssignment -ObjectId "859f0f40-057b-4afc-9d05-fe8b3933ae87" -RoleDefinitionName Owner -Scope "/subscriptions/*****************/resourceGroups/shuiapp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/shuicli"
```

Note: You could get your user object ID with cmdlet `get-azureaduser`.

Azure CLI

You could use [`az role assignment create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/role/assignment?view=azure-cli-latest#create) to do this.

For example.

```
az role assignment create --assignee <user object id> --role Owner --scope "/subscriptions/3b4d41fa-e91d-4bc7-bc11-13d221b3b77d/resourceGroups/shuiapp/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/shuicli"
```

Note: If your user is Azure AD user, you could use `az ad user list` to get user's object id. If your user is a service principal, you could use `az ad sp list` to get object id.

Comment: Hi, do you use Azure CLI 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: It worked like a charm for WebSites, can you give just one sample value for --scope in case of Azure Functions

Comment: I used CLI 2.0, but I tried your solution for PowerShell, it worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Hi, Azure Function is same with Web app. `providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<function name>`

Comment: In fact, function is also a web app. So the provider is `Microsoft.Web/sites`.

Comment: Great, it worked for the Functions as well, thanks a ton @Walter!